# CruiseControl email error

Tags: cruisecontrol

I m getting following error when trying to send a email to a gmail account from CruiseControl.

javax.mail.MessagingException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Appreciate any idea to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

See if this patch helps you.
http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CC-277